# How do I add tab view in the scrollable activity like shown in the picture?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, scrollable, tabview

like shown in the link
https://dribbble.com/shots/2339508-Dark-Profile-Screen

when I try to put view pager down the activity it does not hold the fragment.
Only the tablayout appears. I have tried keeping viewpager outside the nestedScrollableView and keeping the content of fragments inside nested scrollableview still fragments are not scrolling inside the activity.Thanks in advance.

```
   `<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/myScrollingContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <com.github.florent37.diagonallayout.DiagonalLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            app:diagonal_angle="35"
            app:diagonal_position="bottom"
            app:diagonal_direction="left">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/coverImage"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/kygo" />

        </com.github.florent37.diagonallayout.DiagonalLayout>

        <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumbnailview"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/kygo"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            app:civ_border_color="#ffffff"
            app:civ_border_width="5dp"
           />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/thumbnailview"
            android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="ALAN WALKER"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnailview"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/thumbnailview"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:weightSum="9"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/diagonalLayout"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="45"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#3E3E3E"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Videos"
                    android:textColor="#3E3E3E"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:textSize="14sp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/diagonalLayout"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="12"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#3E3E3E"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Views"
                    android:textColor="#3E3E3E"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:textSize="14sp"/>


            </LinearLayout>

                        </LinearLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/buttons"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>`
```

Comment: We need code in order to tell you what's wrong

Comment: Hi, I have added the code for the reference.

Comment: I need the adapter and the actual Java or kotlin code the XML is fine